# How to make JOptionPane on top of a Fullscreen Window?

Tags: java, window, jpanel, fullscreen, joptionpane

I couldn't find any spesific solution for Fullscreen Window so I want to ask. How to make a JOptionPane on the top of a Fullscreen Window?

In here , Im taking a Fullscreen window as a constructor parameter. But when I press ESC , my window sending itself to background, like I pressed "Alt+Tab". Then if I click on if from start menu bar , I can see it on top of window. But I want to end this sending background problem.How can I fix it?

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class KeyListenerTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
  private Window windo;
  private ImageIcon quitImage;

  public KeyListenerTest(Window window)
  {
    quitImage = new ImageIcon("quitask.png");
    windo = window;
    addKeyListener(this);
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {  
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
      JOptionPane opti = new JOptionPane();
      int choice = opti.showConfirmDialog(windo, "Do you really want to quit?", "QUIT", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION , 
                                          JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE  , quitImage);
      opti.requestFocusInWindow();
      if(choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
      {
        System.exit(0);
      }
      else
      {
        dispose();
        System.out.println("ESC key typed");
      }
    }
  }  
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  } 
}
```

And here is my code for making my window fullscreen

```
  window=(Window)frame;
  window.setFocusable(true);

  KeyListenerTest keyo = new KeyListenerTest(window);
  frame.addKeyListener(keyo);

  g.setFullScreenWindow(window);
```

Comment: Not sure if it is going to work or not. But change `windo` into `this` when you showing confirm dialog from JOptionPane..

Comment: Now JOptionPane pops up in the center of screen but now my background window is becoming invisible. I want to see both my window and JOptionPane

Comment: You can make this JFrame a JWindow.. What are you expecting with a background Window. I think it would be easy if you had a JFrame in background..

Comment: Can you explain this a little? Im confused. Because in ´KeyListenerTest´ Im not using any any JFrame. And I cannot change my background because Its connected with bunch of other classes. By the way , If Im not wrong , JWindow and Window classes are different.

Comment: Yes they are different.. `KeyListenerTest` is made by extending JFrame. That means, `KeyListenerTest` is a JFrame. And I said it you can extend your class with JWindow, not JFrame. And when you are making a instance of your class, make it a model. (by calling `setModel`)

Comment: I changed my code by extending with JWindow but I dont know how to make it model. Im creating instance of my class with this code `KeyListenerTest keyo = new KeyListenerTest(window);` how am I suppose to make it model and where should I call setModel? Im am sorry , I am not familiar with JWindow and setModel method.

Comment: just call `keyo.setModel(yourBackgroudWindow)` after construction.. Hope this will give you an answer..

Comment: `frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` solved my problem. Thanks for all of you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
frame.setSize(300, 200); //or any other size you want for JFrame after changeing from maximalized state
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

instead of:

```
g.setFullScreenWindow(window);
```

works for me.

Comment: @BlocBloc Setting a window to fill the whole screen in terms of size is *not* the same as setting it to fullscreen mode.

Comment: What is the difference , may I ask?

Comment: @BlocBloc now i see, user1803551 is right, setExtendedState() only set screen size for frame, but not maximize it in a fact. You still can use maximize button in extendet state, and if you use 'escape', there is still same problem as before

Comment: What would be the possible problem for my program If I use setExtendedState() rather than using setFullScreenWindow() ? Because It seems , its working like the same

Comment: @BlocBloc i am not sure, but I edited my answer, and now it maximized frame, not only set max size. You can chage setSize() as you wish

Comment: @BlocBloc [Read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html).

Comment: I see , thanks a lot for your warning. Since It's fine for me right now , I will stick with m.cekiera's solution.